# Which specific questions should we promote on other SE sites?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

[This answer](https://communitybuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1231/83) on the question about submitting community ads on other (graduated) Stack Exchange sites suggests promoting individual questions:

> We can probably get away with something non-picturey (it's a word now...). I have seen several for UX.SE that are very simple. I can't find their recent ads on their Meta, but some of their older ones, [here](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/626/community-promotion-ads-2012), are just boiled down versions of their questions with links back to the relevant question.

That's a great idea.  (Thanks Andy!)  So, which specific questions from our site should we advertise on other sites?  Questions should be well-written and relevant to the target community and ideally should have at least one good answer.

Please post one suggestion per answer, linking to the question and saying what site(s) we should submit it to.

Comment: The answers I've posted so far are from a walk down the site's main page (recent activity).

Answer (score 5):

[How to say "We miss you, please come back!" properly?](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/883/we-miss-you-please-come-back)

Site: User Experience

I've seen questions there about web-site registration and retention, and also questions about how to word user-facing messages.

Comment: Ad is here: http://meta.communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/a/1282/83

Comment: This ad is currently live on UX.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe:

[Community Leader is not productive and hurts site growth](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/939/how-to-deal-with-a-community-leaders-mood-swings-and-low-productivity)

Site: Workplace

Workplace's scope includes "people" stuff -- management, dealing with management, and peer groups.  It seems like this could be a fit there, probably with a slightly tweaked title in the ad.

Comment: "How do I deal with a low performing community leader?" I'm not sure of Workplace's scope. Is "community leader" appropriate for the scope?

Comment: @Andy I think we might want to tweak the wording somehow.  Issues with managers, team leaders, project managers, and all that sort of stuff are in scope there; in terms of the *problems*, moderators feel similar (except for the salary and "affect your employment" parts).  Maybe just drop the word "community" (it'll be obvious from the site name anyway)?

Comment: "How do I deal with a low performing leader?" - I've looked for duplicates on Workplace and I'm not seeing any related to the leaders. My results have shown a couple for low performing team members.

Comment: Some "higher-ups aren't as good as they should be" examples: http://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/28250/325, http://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/22559/325, and this "WTF ethics?" one: http://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/39031/325

Answer (score 4):

[How to deal with a stubborn person who thinks they are perfect?](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/896/how-to-deal-with-a-stubborn-person-who-thinks-they-are-perfect)

Sites: Workplace, Skeptics (h/t Jan Doggen)

The "coworker" version of this would fit in there, so this doesn't seem a stretch.

Comment: Maybe retitle (for the ad, I mean, not the actual question) "How do you deal with a stubborn know-it-all?".

Comment: Workspace version of the ad here: http://meta.communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/a/1283/83

Comment: This ad is currently live on Workplace.

Answer (score 3):

[Should I do anything to protect, or even privilege, minority opinions on my site?](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/151/should-i-do-anything-to-protect-or-even-privilege-minority-opinions-on-my-site)

The graduated religion sites (currently Mi Yodeya and Christianity), and Academia.

<sup>Note: Even though I'm a moderator on Mi Yodeya, I don't actually know how well-received this would be by my community.  But it doesn't hurt to ask.</sup>

Answer (score 3):

[Do badges (gamification) produce positive results in a professional community?](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/929/do-badges-gamification-produce-positive-results-in-a-professional-community)

Site: User Experience

(It feels like there might be another site where this fits; I think I remember a discussion about it.  If you remember what it was, please edit or comment.)

Comment: I've been watching, but not committed, to the gamefication proposal. It's obviously no where near graduation, but this seems like it'd be relevant for their proposal too.

Comment: Yeah, definitely relevant for them.  And in 3 or 4 years we could run it as an ad on their site. :-)

Answer (score 3):

[When is it acceptable to single out a user?](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/1088/when-is-it-acceptable-to-single-out-a-user)

Site: Workplace, changing the title to something like "How do I respond to a disruptive meeting participant?".

Meeting hell -- it's not just for communities.  Every workplace I've seen has this problem at some point.

Comment: Alternate proposed ad text: "Meeting hell: what do you do about the disruptive participant?"

Answer (score 1):

[Detecting and preventing hostility to women?](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/990/detecting-and-preventing-hostility-to-women)

Site: Arqade (Gaming)

I didn't follow "GamerGate" closely, but I have the impression that this question is in the same space as that issue.  This question might therefore be of current interest there.  (This is probably not an ad for the long-term.)